# Does "frame" or "framework" work for the following context?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I want to say that someone can study by-himself but he needs a "**frame**" or "**framework**" meaning that he needs to be in an institute that will manage and coach him.

Now based on my native language the translation is "frame" or "framework", but I couldn't find evidence for such usage. I've check the meaning of both words in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/frame) and [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/frame) but I didn't find such meaning.

Comment: Have you considered using the term **guidance**?

Comment: An institute might provide a framework but it is not itself a framework.

Comment: @Cookie  for me it is more than just guidance.

Comment: well, I agree with what @Tᴚoɯɐuo. One thing is for sure, "frame" is definitely not the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think **framework** is the best word here. I'm not sure what you're trying to describe, but you might consider one of the following:

A **curriculum** refers to the lessons taught in a course or program of study. I feel like this might be the word you're seeking.

A **syllabus** is a document outlining the subjects taught in a class.

A **program** is a series of courses offered by a school that focus on a particular subject. For example, a "creative writing program" would normally belong to the English Department of a liberal arts college. The program often has its own teachers and administrators, so the students would have **mentorship** and other resources available to them.

Comment: Thank you but I can not be sure in the answer while I'm not sure that you understood me.  I'm trying to say for example, that a pupil in 13 years old should be in a "learning frame" rather than to work in market.  Or another examples that I showed. By the way, curriculum is not the one that I seek for. all the rest I knew as well.

Comment: Can you describe the learning frame more? Does it involve teachers? Does the frame refer to the framework of a single course or many courses? Does it refer just to books and study materials, or to something bigger?

Comment: Maybe you need a whole phrase rather than a single word - something like **an environment designed for learning**.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I think you're right, because I can't think of a single word that exists that describes "an institution that will manage and coach" aside from "program." A program doesn't HAVE to be a set of courses. It can be just a weekly or monthly class or meeting for students and/or parents.